# how to compare two dataframes with different indexes, and output new column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have two dataframes, one contains some of the same values as another (in the same columns). If they match, I want to add the value of 1 to a new column, and if they don't match I want to add the value of 0.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
list1 = []
for l in list1:
      or i in incidents_df['incident']:
         if re.search(l, i):
             list1.append(1)
         else:
             list1.append(0)
incidents_df['y/n'] = list1
```

also tried:

```
list1 = []
for i in incidents_df['incident'].astype(str):
    if other_df['incident'].astype(str) == i:
        list1.append(1)
    else:
        list1.append(0)
incidents_df['y/n'] = list1
```

I get errors for both

Comment: It's complicated to help you without a sample of data for testing, and expected output. Try this: `new_col = np.where(incidents_df['incident'] == other_df['incident'], 1, 0)`.

Comment: May you provide us a reproducible example with an expected output, thanks.

Comment: @ADUBEY expected output for list1 would be [0, 1, 0, 0, 1] where len(list1) == incidents_df['incident'].count()

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva i tried that, the problem is that the indexes of other_df != the indexes of incidents_df

Comment: Using `.isin` might solve: `incidents_df['incident'].astype(str).isin(other_df['incident'].astype(str)).astype(int).tolist()`

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by "different indexes"? You mean there's a different amount of rows, or just the labels are different?

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva yes, different amount of rows

Comment: Yes, `np.where` is good for when the index of the series is the same. Every series in a dataframe has an index, so if there are two different dataframes with different values on there indices, then it can create an error or return unexpected results if sorted differently or an index was reset in one dataframe, etc. While `isin` just searches for the raw value of the series and index is irrelevant. You could also probably merge one column on the incident column. Then, you could make NaN values false and non-NaN values True.